# how to summarise a numeric variable by two factors in R

Tags: r, sum, aggregate, data.table, dplyr

I have a data.frame with 3 variables and 1.425.558 observations. It´s a register of installed electric power from renewable energy plants. Every row stands for one installed power plant. There can be multiple power plants of the same type in a zipcode-area.

```
ID  zipcode     Type    power
1   79280   solarpower  3
2   79280   solarpower  3
3   79283   hydroelectric   3
4   79280   biogas          55
5   79280   windpower   2
6   21459   windpower   4
7   21459   windpower   2
```

I would like to sum by zipcode how much solarpower/biogas/windpower is installed.

```
zipcode     Type    power
21459        windpower    6
79280        solarpower   6
79280        windpower    2
...and so on.
```

I already tried

```
aggregate(myDat$power, by=list(myDat$zipcode,myDat$type), FUN=sum)
```

but my RAM was not sufficant.

I know, my dataframe is very big. I could narrow it down a lot, because i only need the data for those zipcodes that start with "2".

Could you point me to a solution?
Thank you very much for helping an Beginner!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you need, you can express it using dplyr:

```
> data %.% group_by( zipcode, Type ) %.% summarise( power = sum(power) )
Source: local data frame [5 x 3]
Groups: zipcode

  zipcode          Type power
1   21459     windpower     6
2   79280     windpower     2
3   79280        biogas    55
4   79283 hydroelectric     3
5   79280    solarpower     6
```

And if you only want those zip code that start by `2`, you can `filter` first:

```
> data %.% filter( grepl( "^2", zipcode ) ) %.% 
     group_by( zipcode, Type ) %.% summarise( power = sum(power) )
Source: local data frame [1 x 3]
Groups: zipcode

  zipcode      Type power
1   21459 windpower     6
```

Answer (score 4):

`data.table` version:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(your_df)

dt[, sum(power), by = list(zipcode, Type)]
```

And to narrow down first:

```
dt[grep("^2", zipcode), sum(power), by = list(zipcode, Type)]
```

Because `grep` is expensive, in both `dplyr` and `data.table` you're likely better off (speed-wise) summarizing first, and filtering second, i.e.:

```
dt[, sum(power), by = list(zipcode, Type)][grep("^2", zipcode)]
```

Comment: using `perl=TRUE` argument to `grep` helps speed things up a bit.

Comment: Also, if you know that the zip code is always 5-digits, you can do: `zipcode %/% 10000 == 2` (no conversion to character could also save more time).